# Unable to start activity componentInfo on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am currently having a problem with my java code. I app is crashing each time i click on my view button. On my logcat I am getting an error message which is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException and the other error is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.moviemanager/com.example.moviemanager.viewmoviedetails}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException**

This is my viewmoviedetails code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewmoviedetail);

    keyEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.keyeditText);
    titleEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleeditText);
    typeEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.typeeditText);
    storyEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.storyeditText);
    ratingEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratingeditText);
    languageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.languageeditText);
    runtimeEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.runtimeeditText);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");

    Button btnback = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    btnback.setOnClickListener(backButtonClicked);
}
OnClickListener backButtonClicked = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        finish();
    }
};
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new LoadMovieTask().execute(rowID);
}

private class LoadMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor>{
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(viewmoviedetails.this);

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params){
        dh.open();
        return dh.getRow(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        result.moveToFirst();
        int keyindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvkey");
        int titleindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvtitle");
        int typeindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvtype");
        int storyindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvstory");
        int ratingindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvrating");
        int languageindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvlanguage");
        int runtimeindex = result.getColumnIndex("mvruntime");

        keyEditText.setText(result.getString(keyindex));
        titleEditText.setText(result.getString(titleindex));
        typeEditText.setText(result.getString(typeindex));
        storyEditText.setText(result.getString(storyindex));
        ratingEditText.setText(result.getString(ratingindex));
        languageEditText.setText(result.getString(languageindex));
        runtimeEditText.setText(result.getString(runtimeindex));

        result.close();
        dh.close();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve my error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `extras` is `null` in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method.

**EDIT:**

In your `ViewMovie` class, you are starting the next `Activity` with

```
 i = new Intent(this, com.example.moviemanager.viewmoviedetails.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that you have not added the extra data to the `Intent`, so when you call

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

in `ViewMovieDetails`, you get `null`.

You need to add the extra to the `Intent` like this:

```
i = new Intent(this, com.example.moviemanager.viewmoviedetails.class);
i.putExtra("row_id", (long) row_id)
startActivity(i);
```

where `row_id` is the `long` value you want to pass. Then recover that value in `ViewMovieDetails` as

```
rowID = getIntent().getLongExtra("row_id", 0L);
```

This will work.

Comment: How can i solve it? I am totally newbie to android app development. Even this code i tried to take it from the android book. Are there any changes i should do for the coding part? @ZygoteInit

Comment: can you post the code where you are creating the `Intent` for this `Activity` ?

Comment: @Zygotelnit I am so sorry but I dont get it by "Intent for this Activity" mean? Did u mean this code 
`public void onClick(View v){
  Intent i;
  switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.txtMovieId:
   i = new Intent(this, com.example.moviemanager.viewmoviedetails.class);
   startActivity(i);
  }
 }`

Comment: @Zygotelnit It still not working I am getting a new error now.

Comment: @RaajLokanathan: the basic problem is that you are not passing the extra ... just fix it and it will work